# CoreStore how to observe changes in database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, corestore

I need to observe changes of an `Entity` after import occurred.

Currently I have next logic:

1. Save `Entity` with temp identifier (`NSManagedObject.objectId`) to local core data storage.
2. Send `Entity` to the server via `Alamofire` `POST` request.
3. Server generates JSON and reply with the almost the same Entity details but with modified identifier which was `NSManagedObject.objectId` previously. So the local one Entity id will be updated with server id.
4. Now when I received new JSON I do `transaction.importUniqueObjects`.

At this step I want to inform my datasource about changes. And refetch data with updated identifiers.

So my `DataSource` has some `Entities` in an array, and while I use this datasource to show data it's still static information in that array which I fetched before, but as you see on the step number 4 I already updated core data storage via `CoreStore` import and want DataSource's array to be updated too.

I found some information regarding ListMonitor in CoreStore and tried to use it. As I can see this method works when update comes

func listMonitorDidChange(_ monitor: ListMonitor)

but I try to refetch data somehow. Looks like monitor already contains some most up to date info.

but when I do this:

```
func listMonitorDidChange(_ monitor: ListMonitor<MyEntity>) {

    let entities = try? CoreStore.fetchAll(
                From<MyEntity>()
                    .orderBy(.ascending(\.name))
            ) // THERE IS STILL old information in database, but monitor instance shows new info.
    }
```

And then code became like this:

```
func listMonitorDidChange(_ monitor: ListMonitor<MyEntity>) {

        var myEntitiesFromMonitor = [MyEntity]()

        for index in 0...monitor.numberOfObjects() {
            myEntitiesFromMonitor.append(monitor[index])
        }

        if myEntitiesFromMonitor.count > 0 {
            // HERE we update DataSource
            updateData(with: myEntitiesFromMonitor) 
        }

    }
```

not sure if I am on the right way.

Comment: Why do you need to store an additional array with your (managed) objects? The monitor is holding and updating them for you, that is why you have it in first place. Make your datasource to use the monitor to access the data and nothing else or you will easily run into inconsistency crashes.

Comment: well let me see. I just fetched object via fetchAll, but yea I guess it's make senes to work with objects via monitor.

Comment: @MartinM thanks for suggestion! your answers and comments are everytime helpful! I overthink the problem before. Now it works, just small question can search through monitor? Looks like there is should be some filter feature using `.where` condition. Just wonder would be this expensive everytime re init monitor  with new `.where` condition for example every time I type letter in search field to update tableview with new data.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong:

As I understood each time core data gets updated with new changes, monitor gets updated as well. I have not dive deep into it how this was made, via some CoreData context notification or whatever but after you do something via CoreStore transaction, such as create or update or delete object or whatever you want, monitor gets update. Also it has callback functions that you need to implement in your class where you want to observe any changes with data model:

Your classes such as datasource or some service or even some view controller (if you don't use any MVVP or VIPER or other design patterns) need to conform to `ListObserver` protocol in case you want to listen not to just one object.

here are that functions:

```
    func listMonitorDidChange(monitor: ListMonitor<MyPersonEntity>) {
        // Here I reload my tableview and this monitor already has all needed info about sections and rows depend how you setup monitor.
        // So you classVariableMonitor which I provide below already has up to date state after any changes with data.
    }



    func listMonitorDidRefetch(monitor: ListMonitor<MyPersonEntity>) {
        // Not sure for which purposes it. I have not received this call yet
    }



typealias ListEntityType = ExerciseEntity

let classVariableMonitor = CoreStore.monitorSectionedList(
    From<ListEntityType>()
    .sectionBy(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)) { (sectionName) -> String? in
        "\(String(describing: sectionName)) years old"
    }
        .orderBy(.ascending(\.name))
        .where(
            format: "%K == %@",
            #keyPath(ListEntityType.name),
            "Search string")
    )
```

All other thing documented [here](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore#observe-a-list-of-objects) so you can find info how to extract info from monitor in your tableview datasource function.

Thanks @MartinM for suggestion!